# Find a row in a Julia DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, julia, julia-dataframe

What's the canonical way of finding a row in a DataFrame in DataFrames.jl?

For instance, given this DataFrame:

```
│ Row  │ uuid                                 │ name                          
│      │ String                               │ String                       
├──────┼──────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────
│ 1    │ 0efae8bf-39e6-5d65-b05d-c8947f4cee2a │ COSMA_jll                    
│ 2    │ 17ccb2e5-db19-44b3-b354-4fd16d92c74e │ CitableImage
```

Given the name "CitableImage", what's the best way to retrive the uuid?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would typically use:

```
filter(:name => ==("CitableImage"), df)
```

which produces a data frame as you can have more than one matching row.

If you are sure that only one row will match then you can also write:

```
df[only(findall(==("CitableImage"), df.name)), :]
```

(the `only` function checks that you picked only one row)

If you want to get a data frame using indexing you can write:

```
df[df.name .== "CitableImage", :]
```

or

```
df[findall(==("CitableImage"), df.name), :]
```

Finally we also provide the `subset` function, but its normal use case is a bit different so here is is more verbose than `filter`:

```
subset(df, :name => ByRow(==("CitableImage")))
```

If you want to do many lookups and want them to be efficient then it is better to do the following:

```
gdf = groupby(df, :name)
```

and then do:

```
gdf[("CitableImage",)]
```

which will be much faster if you do many such lookups.

Comment: Hi Bogumił! Off-topic for this post (apologies for hijacking this), but I noticed that there is a dataframes.jl tag on Stack Overflow, as well as a julia-dataframes tag. I was wondering, would you consider them synonyms? I would suggest it, but it appears I need a score of 5 in the julia-dataframes tag to suggest it. Interested to hear your thoughts!

Comment: I think it is better to tag questions regarding DataFrames.jl to be tagged `julia` and `dataframe` (two separate tags). The `julia-dataframe` tag is very rarely used, so I think it is not that useful.

Comment: perhaps both should be burninated. I'll ask on meta. Thanks for answering! :-)